# prove that for $n \ge 4, {{2n}\choose{n}} \ge n\cdot2^n$

Tags: analysis, inequality, binomial-coefficients

Prove that for $n \ge 4$
 $${{2n}\choose{n}} \ge n\times2^n$$

I tried like that:

$T_4$: ${{8}\choose{4}} = 70 \ge 4\times2^4$ = 64 so it's ok

$T_{n+1}$: $$\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!)(n+1)!} \ge n\times2^{n+1}+2^{n+1}$$
          $$\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!)(n+1)!} \ge n\times2^n\times2+2*2^n=2^n(2n+2)$$
$$\frac{(2n+1)2n!}{(n+1)^2n!n!} \ge 2^n$$
$$\frac{(2n+1)2n!}{n!n!} \ge (n+1)^2\times2^n = 2^n\times n\times2+2^n\times n^2+2^n$$ and we know from assigment that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!} \ge n\times2^n$.
I'm stuck right here because I tried to do a trick which is probably not correct.

I just would like to get a hint how to finish that **by induction** or if you can just finish my proof.

Comment: If you know that ${2n\choose n}\ge n\cdot 2^n$, then multiplying by $2(n+1)\over n$ on both sides should preserve the inequality and get you a bit closer...

Answer (score 1):

Inductive step is

$${{2(k+1)}\choose{k+1}} = {{2k}\choose{k}}\times \frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{(k+1)^2}\ge k\times 2^k\times\frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{(k+1)^2}= k\times 2^{k+1}\times\frac{(2k+1)}{(k+1)}\ge (k+1)\times 2^{k+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Let }\binom{2m}m>m\cdot 2^m$$

$$\implies \binom{2(m+1)}{m+1}=\frac{2(m+1)(2m+1)}{(m+1)^2}\cdot\binom{2m}m$$
$$>\frac{2(2m+1)}{m+1} m2^m=\frac{(2m+1)m}{m+1}2^{m+1}$$

So, it is sufficient to show that $$\frac{(2m+1)m}{m+1}>m+1\iff m^2-m-1>0$$ which is true if $m>1$